# Converting Other statement in analytics.js to gtag.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

How should this be converted?

The Other section should use the FIRST-ID, tag without knowing it explicitly.

**First Account and Second Account**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'FIRST-ID', { 'allowAnchor': true });
    ga('set', 'page', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash);
    ga('set', 'hostname', 'example.com');
    ga('set', 'userId', 'test');
    ga('set', 'UserName', 'test');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    ga('create', 'SECOND-ID', 'auto', 'member', { 'allowAnchor': true });
    ga('member.set', 'page', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash);
    ga('member.set', 'hostname', 'example.com');
    ga('member.send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```

**Other**

```
if (typeof ga != 'undefined') {
            ga('send', 'pageview', {
                'page': ('/' + encodeURIComponent(url))
            });
        }
```

Comment: What problems are you having with converting it, the question is kinda broad as is?

Comment: I think the main thing is the Other statement, what is the equivalent of that?